# How can I change a Google Chrome flag with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I change a Google Chrome flag (chrome://flags/) with a keyboard shortcut?

For example, I'd like to map a keyboard shortcut to set chrome://flags/ `#enable-force-dark` to `enabled`.

I use Google Chrome on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate and Microsoft Windows 10 Pro.